# Find the intersection of two functions, $f(x) = \tan x$ and $g(x) = 5x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I can't proceed with the normal method to find these ones because they will intersect infinite times. Should I take an interval?

$$f(x)=\tan(x), \qquad g(x)=5x$$

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just have to give one intersection? Can you just say $x=0$ and not bother with the other intersections?

Comment: You are looking for solutions of the equation
$$\tan(x)=5x. $$

First, obviously, $0$ is a solution. 

Second, both functions are continuous ($f$ is continuous over its domain, that is, for $x\neq n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z})$. Define $$h(x)=\tan(x)-5x, $$
so you can use the mean value theorem to approximate a solution. 

Third, there is several methods for solving the fixed point problem $\tan(x)=5x.$

Comment: What's the "normal method"? It might give some ideas for answers if the question said what you would have done if there were not infinitely many intersections.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily find the trivial intersection at $x=0$ and for $x>0$ each one of the others solutions are contained in the intervals

$$n\pi<x<\frac{\pi}2+n\pi \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

and can be found by numerical methods.

Answer (score 2):

As gimusi answered, discrading the trivial solution $x=0$, you have a root $x_n$ such that
$$n \pi < x_n  < \left(n+\frac 12\right)\pi$$ Plotting the function, you noticed that the solutions are very close to the right bound.

To get rid of the discontinuities, consider instead looking for the zero's of function
$$F(x)=\sin(x)-5x \cos(x)$$ You can get quite good estimates of the solution expanding $F(x)$ as a truncated Taylor series built at $x=\left(n+\frac 12\right)\pi$. Limited to
$O\left(\left(x-\frac{2 n+1}{2} \pi  \right)^3\right)$, this would give as the equation to solve
$$9 y^2-5 (2   n+1 )\pi y+2=0\qquad \text{where} \qquad y=\left(n+\frac 12\right)\pi-x_n$$ As a result,
$$x_n \approx \frac{2}{9}   (2 n+1)\pi+\frac{1}{18} \sqrt{25 (2   n+1 )^2\pi^2-72}$$ Checking for a few values of $n$,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 1.4325167 &  1.4320322 \\
 1 & 4.6695980 &  4.6695848 \\
 2 & 7.8284421 &  7.8284393 \\
 3 & 10.977358 &  10.977357 
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $n >3$, there is no difference at the level of $8$ significant figures.

You could have simpler estimates using the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant built at $x=\left(n+\frac 12\right)\pi$. This would give as solution
$$x_n \approx \left(n+\frac 12\right)\pi-\frac{10 (2   n+1 )\pi}{25 (2   n+1 )^2\pi^2-18}$$ which is as good as the previous one.

If you need more accuracy, use Newton method starting from one of these estimates. The iterates will be given by
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{\sin (x_k)-5 x_k \cos (x_k)}{5 x_k \sin (x_k)-4 \cos (x_k)}$$ For the first root, we should then have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_k \\
 0 & 1.4325167001302000019 \\
 1 & 1.4320324138494111588 \\
 2 & 1.4320322362434419819 \\
 3 & 1.4320322362434180905
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for  $20$ significant figures.

Comment: If you look into more details, you would notice that, for large values of $n$, the distance betwenn the root and the asymptote is almost $\frac 1 {5\pi n}$